# Mechanical keyboard - characters getting skipped while typing in fast speed?

Tags: keyboard

So I'm actually new to mechanical keyboards and have just replaced a Dell membrane keyboard with a RGB backlit mechanical.

The keys and the feedback feel great when compared to a membrane counterpart. However I'm noticing that when I type at a fast speed, certain characters get skipped despite me feeling the switch getting pressed for each key. This has resulted in a lot of typos and it did not happen with a membrane board.

I'm also noticing that I need to put some extra pressure on the keys to have them type properly without missing anything. But this has lowered my typing speed considerably.

So is this normal with a mechanical keyboard? Putting in extra pressure on keys to have them output everything? What my observation is with this one is that a switch will register that 'click' sound but the character gets skipped. I don't see it as an OS compatibility issue or power related either (I'm using Linux).

Answer (score 1):

> What my observation is with this one is that a switch will register that 'click' sound but the character gets skipped.

You will need a bit of understanding of electronics here, but here lies the rub with any electromechanical device. You may get a satisfying click of a switch registering movement of the mechanical part of the device, which not only has an audible feedback, but with some mechanical keyboards you get a kinetic feedback with the slight resistance at the point just before the click.

But, the switch contacts might not have a strong enough connection for the electronics part to register the contact being made. This can be either because of lack of pressure on the contacts or because of electrical resistance build-up.

If there are food particles, dust or other dirt between the electrical contacts, the button press will be harder to register due to the electrical resistance of whatever is between them.

Because there is a mechanical element to the device, there can also be a small latency between the button press and the electrical registering of the press.

Some are more prone to latency than others and you would need to do very careful research before purchasing if you want a particularly low latency device.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. Its a new keyboard so I don't think there's any dust or anything of that sort in between. Sadly I do not have a concrete reason why I should be returning this product to the store from where I bought. The keys are great but I'll probably test it out for a couple of days and file a return if this keeps happening.

Comment: As you said, there is no concrete reason to return other than it is not as responsive as you require. If you do get another one, research the most responsive mechanical keyboard or go for another non-mechanical one.